# hoisting and updating list with custom type in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I got some issuse by trying to hoist a MutableList.
The List is initializied in the MainActivity

```
package com.example.jetnoteapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import com.example.jetnoteapp.ui.theme.JetNoteAppTheme
import com.example.jetnoteapp.view.JetNoteUi

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val noteList = remember { mutableStateListOf<NoteItem>() }

            noteList.add(NoteItem("Relaxing", "the whole day"))
            noteList.add(NoteItem("Take photos", "Sony or Canon?"))

            JetNoteAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    JetNoteUi(
                        noteList = noteList,
                        addToNoteList = { newNote -> noteList.add(newNote) },
                        removeFromNoteList = { noteIndex -> noteList.removeAt(noteIndex) }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "NoteItem" is declared in a dataclass like so:

```
package com.example.jetnoteapp

data class NoteItem(var title: String, var description: String)
```

Now i can hoist the declarde List to the Composable function, but with the given lambdas I got an error in the JetNotUi composable.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is com.example.jetnoteapp.view.JetNoteUi.NoteItem but com.example.jetnoteapp.NoteItem was expected

package com.example.jetnoteapp.view

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.jetnoteapp.NoteItem
import com.example.jetnoteapp.showJetNoteToast

@Preview
@Composable
fun JetNoteUi(
    noteList: List<NoteItem> = listOf(),
    addToNoteList: (NoteItem) -> Unit = {},
    removeFromNoteList: (Int) -> Unit = {}
) {
    data class NoteItem(var title: String, var description: String)

    var title by remember {mutableStateOf("")}
    var description by remember { mutableStateOf("")}
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Scaffold(
        modifier=Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        topBar={
               TopAppBar(backgroundColor = Color.Blue) {
                   Text(text="JetNoteApp", fontSize=14.sp, color=Color.White)
               }
        }
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(13.dp)) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                JetNoteInputField(
                    label = "title",
                    value = title,
                    onValueChange = { title = it }
                )
                JetNoteInputField(
                    label = "description",
                    value = description,
                    onValueChange = { description = it }
                )
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        if (title.isNotEmpty() && description.isNotEmpty()) {
                            addToNoteList(NoteItem(title, description))
                            title = ""
                            description = ""
                        }
                        else {
                            if (title.isEmpty()) {
                                showJetNoteToast(context, message = "title can't be empty.")
                            }
                            if (description.isEmpty()) {
                                showJetNoteToast(context, message = "description can't be empty.")
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    content = { Text("save") }
                )
            }
            Text(text = "notes:")
            Divider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(3.dp)
                    .padding(top = 2.dp), color = Color.Black
            )
            Column {
                noteList.forEach {
                    JetNoteListItem(
                        title = it.title,
                        description = it.description
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following Error and don't now why. It is the same data class, so why appears this Error!?

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is com.example.jetnoteapp.view.JetNoteUi.NoteItem but com.example.jetnoteapp.NoteItem was expected
```

Comment: It's not the same class, they might have the same properties and the same name but they're declared in different locations. It seems to me like you don't need `NoteItem` to be declared in `JetNoteUi`.

Answer (score -1):

In your activity, you have:

```
val noteList = remember { mutableStateListOf<NoteItem>() }
```

And the package of MainActivity is `package com.example.jetnoteapp`.

Looking at the imports in your MainActivity, there is no import for `NoteItem`, so there must be a class `NoteItem` in the same package, i.e.: com.example.jetnoteapp.NoteItem.

But in your JetNoteUi, there is another definition of NoteItem.

Like below:

```
    data class NoteItem(var title: String, var description: String)
```

And you use it with this line:

```
addToNoteList(NoteItem(title, description))
```

This causes the class mismatched.

Remove this line

```
    data class NoteItem(var title: String, var description: String)
```

from your function, try it again.

BTW, removing it means you will use the same class, which is in the package: `com.example.jetnoteapp.NoteItem`